# Removing Space after <H2>

Tags: php, html, css

I cannot seem to get rid of the space between my heading 2 and the rest of the page.
http://cnghl.biz/cnghldb/cnghlplayerinfo.php?PlayerID=823

```
    Print "<body>";
    Print "<div align='left'>";
    Print "<h2>".$row['FirstName']." ".$row['LastName']."</strong></h2><br>";
    Print "<table width='710' border='0'>";
    Print "<tr>";
    Print "<td width='225'><strong>Birthdate:</strong> ".$row['DOB']."</td><br>";
    Print "<td width='225'><strong>Nation:</strong> ".$row['Nation']."</td><br>";
    Print "<td width='' rowspan='8'><div align='center'><img src=\"
```

I have searched the web for possible answers but I cannot seem to get them to work.
Thanks for your help and happy holidays.

Comment: Are you referring to the extra `<br>` you have placed after your closing `<h2>` tag?

Comment: You have 10 `<br>` tags in your page that are not shown in your code. Are you sure you're looking at the right output?

Comment: First, your syntax does not adhere to best-practices.  Try <h2 style="padding: 0px!important; margin: 0px!important;">' . trim($_row['FirstName']) . ' '

Answer (score 1):

You have 10 < BR > tags which create the space on the output page (when I click the link).  The BR tag forces a line break.  Not sure why  it's ending up there - the code snippet you uploaded might not be the one being called.

Comment: He also needs to add css margin: 0px; padding: 0px;, but yes, get rid of the break as-well

Answer (score 0):

I viewed your source code in the page, I found that the
`<br>` in the table target are at invalid location. So the 10 < BR > tags is caused by that. You need to delete all of the

```
<br>
```

Comment: Delete <br> is such code Print "<td width='225'><strong>Birthdate:</strong> ".$row['DOB']."</td><br>";